Написание иноязычных названий улиц с помощью кириллицы
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пишутся составные названия иностранных улиц, нужны ли дефисы между словами или нет? Ну, например: русское название — улица Чёрной Дыры. А как будет английское? Блэк Хоул стрит / Блэк-хоул-стрит или ещё как?
